# Changing hostname in WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: server, wso2, identity

I'm following `WSO2IS's` guide to changing `hostname` and I feel like they're leaving out a rule that I don't know or they're (again) assuming I should know this.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Changing+the+Hostname

I'll do a quick rundown of what I did and I'll put the questions at the end. Each numbered list header is referring to the steps in that guide respectively.

1. I had my `Hostname/MgtHostname` set as `somename.something.ca`
2. I put the original `wso2carbon.jks` in a separate folder as a backup and created a new keystore `"wso2carbon.jks"` using this commandline with adjusted values :

   ```
   keytool -genkey -alias newcert -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore newkeystore.jks -dname "CN=<testdomain.org>, OU=Home,O=Home,L=SL,S=WS,C=LK" -storepass mypassword -keypass mypassword
   ```
3. I was able to export a public key from my keystore by adjusting the command line to their appropriate values.
4. Same thing as step 3, I just changed the values in the command line so it fit with my alias and public key. I was able to import the public key.
5. Changed `"localhost"` to `"somename.something.ca"` everywhere it existed (`identity.xml`, `authenticators.xml` etc...)

Everything ran smoothly and I started my WSO2IS service. However, I was not able to reach somename.something.ca (URL does not exist) and when I tried to access my IS, the SAML SSO referred to `localhost` again (tried this in Incognito mode too)! I don't know why it kept doing that even after I went into my admin dashboard and changed the SAML SSO Identity Provider name from `localhost` to the new `hostname`.

For now, I just want to be able to refer to `localhost` as a different name and at least be able to access my identity server outside my LAN. I should note that I am testing the WSO2IS on a remote desktop (*Windows Server*) where we do development for the site.

So should I try my `hostname` as my IP? Does my `hostname` actually have to exist or can it just be a placeholder? Does my `hostname` have to be different from 
`'localhost'` so that I may access it outside my LAN? If I change the `hostname`, am I able to access the dashboard as `'localhost'` AND as my new `hostname` through the computer where I'm running `WSO2IS` as a service?

I'm sorry for all the questions, I am new to this stuff and I think there is just so *much* left out of the `WSO2` documentation that I need to know in order to make this work.

Your answers are much appreciated.

---

EDIT:
Now with my new hostname setup (after following the guide) and while I'm running WSO2IS, my localhost won't load. If I try going to localhost (on Chrome), it will take 30s then say "localhost took too long to load."

Comment: `changed the SAML SSO Identity Provider name from localhost` IdP name is only a name, is is not used to redirect a client (I know, it is misleading), could you better described the flow how do you get redirected to the localhost? Is hostname (AssertionConsumerURL) in your application (SP) metadata refering to localhost?  Second - could your client resolve the domain name of the new hostname? Does your reverse proxy trust your new certificate?

Comment: Hey again @gusto2, so what happens is the user is logged into the website and when they want to see this webapp, they must connect to the identity server. So with SAML SSO their credentials are passed and then it will log them in and they can access the webapp. It works fine when I have WSO2IS service running on default (localhost) but if I change the values (like above) it will redirect me to https://localhost:9443/samlsso and give the error "localhost refused to connect"

I couldn't find a variable called AssertionConsumerURL in my SP's metadata, there was AssertionConsumerService but 1/2

Comment: the URL/address it is pointing at is not localhost, it's pointing at it's own authorization URL (I sometimes see it when I'm logging into the webapp). I'm not sure how to check if my client resolves the domain name of the new hostname? Do you mean like if it can connect to it with the proxyPort set? I've tried that before but nothing changed, it just kept saying the domain doesn't exist (no certificate warnings or anything).

Comment: Also, does it matter what you set your hostname to? Like does the URL have to exist or can you just make it up?

Comment: `it will redirect me to localhost:9443/samlsso` What is the IdP SSO URL configured in your web application? (where does the webapp redirects the user?)

Comment: `domain doesn't exist`  in the command ling try `ping your.domain.ca`  you should see the ping trying to connect to an IP address (or different hostname if CNAME is used). If it will say 'unknown host` then you need to setup your DNS first (so the host is recognized)

Comment: Currently my WSO2IS is the resident IdP and I just noticed the SSO URL: localhost:9443/samlsso!! I'm not able to change it though, I'm able to add a Destination URL but the SSO URL remains equal to 'localhost:9443/samlsso'. There's just no option from the dashboard to edit it. Is this done in a separate .xml file?

Comment: And for the second comment, that makes a lot of sense. Would I just be able to configure it to my own websites URL/IP Address instead of registering a new, valid domain?

Comment: `I just noticed the SSO URL`  maybe it doesn't matter. If you access your IS as localhost, it will be localhost, if you access it as something else, it should change.  `Would I just be able to configure it to my own websites URL` you can do it in the hosts file  (I mean .. you just made up a domain name and you assumed it will be recognized by *itself*??)

Comment: I was pretty skeptical about the domain problem, I'm still new to this stuff so I just read in the guides exactly it is and it didn't say anything about the domain naming. I didn't know if WSO2 provided that sort of service as well but yeah, I'm sorry. I'm not sure how to bind it to my hosts file? Would it be a line like this:

[IP ADDRESS] [NAME] [URL]?

Comment: Okay, I'm trying something with the domain name as the one I configured in my hosts file. Hopefully this works.

Comment: @gusto2 So I was able to set the domain in my hosts file. If I try going to localhost:9443/samlsso it will now redirect to my hostname, before it wasn't doing this. However, when I try to connect to my domain/hostname, it says "took too long to respond." Could this be an issue with my keystore? I think this is progress :P

Comment: it should have nothing to do with the keystore (you shall get the "certificate not trusted" message)

Comment: I get that message when I connect to localhost and I've had that multiple times - I guess that's expected? Any idea how to fix this issue with connecting to the new hostname? I got it setup in my hosts file with the URL as the same address as my hostname but when I try to connect it will load for ~15 seconds then say "took too long to respond."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using IIS so what you need to do is create an active website using the manager. I just created a subdomain and plugged that in for every 'localhost' occuring in my .xml files. That allowed me to change my hostname.

Special thanks to gusto2.